# Prove that the absolute value of a holomorphic function is greater than the absolute value of one of its coefficients for some given value.

Tags: complex-analysis

The problem is as follows:
[image]

I can't find such a suitable function as per hint, and I don't see how a3 ≠ 0 comes into play. Could anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you see this kind of condition ($a_3 \ne 0$) one idea is to make it 
"the leading coefficient" in a (perforce nonconstant) polynomial that has $a_0$ as the free term (so $a_0$ is the value at $z=0$) and apply maximum modulus.

So noting that $|g(t)|=|e^{-it}g(t)|, t \in \mathbb R$,

let $f(z)=a_0+a_1z+a_2z^2+a_3z^3$ a polynomial of degree $3$ as $a_3 \ne 0$ so non-constant

$f(0)=a_0$ so by maximum modulus there is $|z|=1, z=e^{it}$ with $|f(e^{it})|>|f(0)|=|a_0|$ since $f$ non-constant and since $|f(e^{it})|=|g(t)|$ as noted above we are done!