# Consequence of minimum modulus principle in complex valued real function.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3 \in \mathbb C$ with $a_3\neq 0$, define $g: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb C$ by $$g(t)=a_0e^{it}+a_1e^{2it}+a_2e^{3it}+a_3e^{4it},$$ show that there is a point $t\in \mathbb R$ such that $|g(t)|>|a_0|$

My attempt:
By considering the holomorphic function $g: \mathbb C \rightarrow \mathbb C$ by $$g(z)=a_0e^{iz}+a_1e^{2iz}+a_2e^{3iz}+a_3e^{4iz},$$ Is there any scope to apply minimum modulus principle on the domain $\{z\in \mathbb C~:~|z|<|a_0|\}$?

Comment: Same question is 3 down if you filter by the complex analysis tag - answer there

Comment: Sir, I am not getting the question under complex analysis tag. Could you please provide a link

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3675289/prove-that-the-absolute-value-of-a-holomorphic-function-is-greater-than-the-abso